# screensaver time reset automatically to 1min. Unable to change Windows 11

Tags: reset, screensaver, windows-11

Unable to change the screensaver time. It reset itself to 1 min every time.

My PC info :
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise
Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000
System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
System Model    Latitude 7490
System Type x64-based PC

Does anyone ever had something similar ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: SO is for programming related questions only. You're looking for [su] instead. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score -1):

Try that type click search icon on taskbar type, gpedit.msc Right click the gpedit and Run As Administrator. On the Left Panel, go to User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Personalization/Enable Screen Saver and Enable the Policy. Then you should change it

Comment: I have tried it already but my issue is when i set the wait time for 90min and save it for example. when i come back after it is 1min again. I don't know what process is resetting it

Comment: Did you try these steps: https://techdirectarchive.com/2022/05/23/how-to-configure-screensaver-timeout-in-windows-10/